# Change Gravity with a Touch C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity

i wonne make a game where the Gravity changes form 1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKoLA.png) to -1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhLIf.png) when i touch one Button  and back when i touch the other button  Button. In the Beginning it works but then it just stops working

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;

       public class Button : MonoBehaviour
     {
       private Rigidbody2D rb;

       private bool moveUp;
     private bool MoveDown;

   // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

      moveUp = false;
     MoveDown = false;

    }


         public void PionterDownRight(){
        moveUp = true;
          }
          public void PionterUpRight(){
           moveUp=false;
           }

       public void PionterDownLeft(){
          MoveDown= true;
          }
         public void PionterUpLeft(){
        MoveDown = false;
          }

     // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
 if(moveUp){
  rb.gravityScale = -1;
 }

 if (MoveDown){
       rb.gravityScale = 1;
 }





}
```

}

Comment: When does PionterDownRight() and the other 3 functions get called?

Comment: Can you show the object hierarchy? How are you adding this script to your player object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend having only one bool variable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool moveDown = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    public void PionterDownRight()
    {
        moveDown = false;
    }
    public void PionterUpRight()
    {
        moveDown = true;
    }

    public void PionterDownLeft()
    {
        moveDown = true;
    }
    public void PionterUpLeft()
    {
        moveDown = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (moveDown == true)
        {
            rb.gravityScale = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.gravityScale = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Graviyscale affects how much gravity will effect the rigidbody, I'm assuming its not working because it plateaus at 0 = no effect. You might have to take a different approach, something like

```
rb.gravityScale = -1;
```

replace with

```
rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 9.81f * 2));
```

Comment: No, `gravityScale` is allowed to be less than 0. That's not the problem. However, I do believe your solution is a viable alternative, after the root problem is solved.